# How to compare a text with array elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on the following demo. How can I do an exact comparison between `test` and elements in an array `arr1`?

```js
var arr1 = ['noël','noel'];
var test = 'noel;

if(){
   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: what is the expected output? if 'noel' in array, return true? otherwise, false?

Answer (score 1):

If you're attempting to determine if test is included in arr1, you may simply:

```
if (arr1.indexOf(test) >= 0) {
    // Test is in arr1!
}
```

The indexOf function returns the index location of an item if it's contained in an array, and `-1`, if it's not in the array.

Comment: No, the semantically proper method to check to see if an array includes an element is `includes` (returns boolean), not `if..indexOf.. >= 0`

Comment: @CertainPerformance: My understanding is that IE doesn't support includes.

Comment: That's what polyfills are for - don't let ancient obsolete browsers keep you from using the modern language tools.

Comment: It depends on the application. I'm all for using modern language tools, but if I'm writing a super simple script, with virtually no other dependencies, I'm not going to force the client to download a library with the polyfill, nor am I going to write my own. There's absolutely nothing wrong with using indexOf in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(arr1.includes(test)){
//Stuff happens
};
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

syntax error at var test='noel';

if you are to extract the differences you can use this

```
var arr1 = ['noël','noel'];
var test = 'noel';
arr1.forEach(function(element)
{
    element==test?null:console.log(element);
});
```